# Error of creating MSALPublicClientApplication object in iOS unit test XCTestCase

Tags: azure-ad-msal

Got this error when run the unit test XCTestCase on iOS platform.

```
Error Domain=MSALErrorDomain Code=-50000 "(null)" UserInfo={MSALErrorDescriptionKey=The required app scheme "msauth.com.apple.dt.xctest.tool" is not registered in the app's info.plist file. Please add "msauth.com.apple.dt.xctest.tool" into Info.plist under CFBundleURLSchemes without any whitespaces and make sure that redirectURi "msauth.com.apple.dt.xctest.tool://auth" is register in the portal for your app., MSALInternalErrorCodeKey=-42001}
```

Follow the error description to add "msauth.com.apple.dt.xctest.tool" into Info.plist for both main app and test target, and register "msauth.com.apple.dt.xctest.tool://auth" in the portal for my app, I still get the error.